# How to use AngularJS in jsf page

Tags: angularjs, jsf, jsf-2

I want to learn AngularJS to use in JSF pages. This is purely learning purpose.
I tried simply add AngularJS code inside the jsf. But seems it doesn't identify the AngularJS code. it simply out put the same `My first expression: {{ 5 + 5 }}` in the browser.

my jsf page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">    
    </script>

    <body>
      <div ng-app="hi" >
         <p>My first expression: {{ 5 + 5 }}</p>
      </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Can anyone help me how to get the output of the AngularJS expression within the jsf page? or show me some direction

## UPDATE

My Actual intention is to get some json from Managebean or from another jsf page and populate here. but for that as testing I tried to create a dummy json structure. but still jsf doesn't identify AngularJS component. It's simply print 
My first expression: {{ 5 + 5 }}
Browser console prints `MyFirstAng.xhtml:24 Uncaught TypeError: app.conntroller is not a function`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div ng-app="myAPP" ng-controller="customerctrl">    
<p>My first expression: {{ 5 + 5 }}</p>

<!-- <ul>
<li ng-repeat="x in myData">
{{x.Name + ', ' + x.Age}}
</li>
</ul>
 -->

 </div>    
</body>    
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">

    var app = angular.module('myAPP',[]);
     app.conntroller('customerctrl', function($scope){

      // $scope.myData=[{Name:'jani',Age:'32'}];
     });

 </SCRIPT> 
</html>
```

Comment: where is `hi` module defined? Have you added it to your index page?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the issue. It was a typo in the `app.controller`. I had type additional "n". it worked. Thanks for all so far guiding me to spot the issue. I thought I am missing to include some AngularJS library or something.

Answer (score 0):

In order for angular to initialize `ng-app="hi"` there needs to exist a *module* with that name. Otherwise you should be seeing an exception thrown in browser dev tools console. Please note console errors when developing javascript apps

Either include a module with that name or remove the name from the attribute and just use `ng-app`

Comment: `message Error Parsing /angular/MyFirstAng.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 7] Attribute name "ng-app" associated with an element type "div" must be followed by the ' = ' character.`    I get this error if I remove the ng-app attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

Either paste this

```
var app = angular.module('hi',[]);
```

in your script or make the `ng-app=""` ... Your choice.
If you specify anything in the `ng-app` then you have to make a module as given above by me. Otherwise just dont specify anything in the `ng-app` i.e. `ng-app=""`. 
At a later stage when you want to make a controller then you can make a module.. For now its best left empty.

Comment: @zaunut  if I remove attribute value I get `message Error Parsing /angular/MyFirstAng.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 7] Attribute name "ng-app" associated with an element type "div" must be followed by the ' = ' character.`   error

Comment: Glad you got the issue....Mark any one answer as the correct answer to mark this question as answered..